# Google Goggles API with jQuery

Tags: jquery, api

I am developing a duplicate content application. I have read [this interesting post](http://notanothercodeblog.blogspot.fr/2011/02/google-goggles-api.html) about a "manual" Google Goggles API. I wonder if it is possible to do the same with jQuery ?

The author talks about a request "body", but I can't find any equivalent in jQuery. However, I do receive a 200 OK response when I generate a CSSID and send a post request with custom headers to http://www.google.com/goggles/container_proto.

Please let me know if you find any workaround of this behavior :)
Thanks !